# Cannot code nested routes with react-router-dom 5.2.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-dom, nested-routes

I'm trying to access to sub components with nested routing in React using react-router-dom 5.2.0.
Here you can find a CodeSandbox link of the project: https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routes-8c7wq?file=/src/App.js

First, let me show you the tree structure of my pages.

- Home
- About
- Organisations

  - MainContent
  - SecondContent

Routes for main pages (Home, About, Organizations) are in src/routes folder.
So their link look like:

- https://localhost:3000/ (for Home)
- https://localhost:3000/about (for About)
- https://localhost:3000/organizations (for Organizations)

At this point, everything is okay for me. The problem is with the nesting part..

On Organizations page, I have to be able to switch between MainContent and SecondContent.
So links into that page must look like this:

- https://8c7wq.csb.app/organizations/maincontent
- https://8c7wq.csb.app/organizations/secondcontent

But I cannot print any of those contents...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build nested paths you should use the `path` and `url` from the current route match and build the nested routes and links from there.

src/pages/Orgainizations

```
import { Switch, Route, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const Organizations = (props) => {
  const { path, url } = useRouteMatch(); // <-- get current path and url
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const menuLinks = {
    data: [
      {
        id: 0, // <-- fix React key issue in NavBar
        title: "StackOverflow",
        to: `${url}/maincontent` // <-- build nested link
      },
      {
        id: 1, // <-- fix React key issue in NavBar
        title: "BitBucket",
        to: `${url}/secondcontent` // <-- build nested link
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar changeValue={(value) => setValue(value)} menuLinks={menuLinks} />
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            render={() => <MainContent title={value} />} // *
            exact
            path={`${path}/maincontent`} // <-- build nested path
            strict
          />
          <Route
            render={() => <SecondContent title={value} />} // *
            exact
            path={`${path}/secondcontent`} // <-- build nested path
            strict
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

***** Notice I converted to rendering route components via the `render` prop as opposed to the `component` prop. When you use anonymous functions to render a component it is created each render cycle, i.e. it will remount the component each time. The `render` prop does not do this. See [render methods](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) for more information.

NavBar

Fix the `to` prop value to render the link correctly, remove the leading "/" from the path and render the direct `link.to` value.

Change

```
to={`/${props.link.to}`}
```

to

```
to={props.link.to}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit cannot-code-nested-routes-with-react-router-dom-5-2-0]